# UICollectionViewCell subviews not sized correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView (subclassed CollectionViewController) inside a container view of another view. The CollectionViewCells are defined in Interface Builder and contain a UIView with some more subviews.

My collection view contains 7 sections with 1 item each. The sections have a defined inset and size (through CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout). Each cell should fill the size of the collection view, without the insets.

The problem seems to be that the view inside the cell is not rendered properly. Using constraints it is set to be fixed to each side, however this does not seem to work.

I have tried logging the widths and heights of the cell itself vs the view inside the cell. As I scroll through the collectionView, all odd cells show the content's size to be far smaller than the cell's. This also applies to the first even cell, but only until I have scrolled to the second even cell. Due to this size difference, the cell's subviews don't render at all.ui

**My IB Setup:**

[image]

**CollectionViewController:**

```
// MARK: CollectionViewController

class DayViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let reuseIdentifier = "DayCell"

    // MARK: CollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayViewCell
        NSLog("%f — %f", cell.bounds.width, cell.content.bounds.width)
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: CollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension DayViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - 40.0, height: collectionView.bounds.height - 40.0)
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width - 40.0, height: collectionView.bounds.height - 40.0)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 20.0)
    }
}
```

**CollectionViewCell:**

```
class DayViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            contentView.frame = bounds
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var content: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rank: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var remainingRep: UILabel!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        layer.cornerRadius = 5

        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 5

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        clipsToBounds = false
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        content.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        content.clipsToBounds = true

        progress.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 22)
    }
}
```

**Running: (odd cell / even cell on first render / even cell on second render)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for making the source available. Some thoughts:

It looks like you're messing with auto layout size classes. I'm not sure you're doing this intentionally.

Select the Container View and then select the Attributes Inspector. At the bottom you'll see some checkboxes. This is showing you that you have the auto layout settings set only for some size classes.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Go into the File Inspector and disable size classes.

[image: Size Classes here]

You'll notice that things start working.

If you're developing just for iPhone (not iPad) and just in portrait orientation, you probably should just disable size classes. If you want to design for those other things, it may help to study up on size classes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the `UICollectionViewController` is in a container view. Is it set up properly so that it's getting all of the expected `UIViewController` calls, such as `viewWillAppear()`?

If you can post a sample project that demonstrates the problem, I'd be happy to try to debug it.

Some thoughts on the code you've posted here:

- In the DayViewCell code, it's highly unusual to be overriding
  `bounds` to set the frame. That concerns me.
- `drawRect()` is not the place to be setting the shadow and corner
  radius. This should be done in `init(frame:)` and/or `init?(coder:)`.
  Doing it in `drawRect()` is expensive and may affect your frame rate 
  when scrolling.
- I'd also move all of the stuff you have in `layoutSubviews()` into
  the `init` methods. There's no advantage to running that code each
  time the view is laid out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I'm still learning in bits and pieces  so pointers as to where things should go are very much appreciated. I have uploaded the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w9vzww72ghrl3r/Wolfswood%20Companion.zip?dl=0.